# html with pdf convertion is not working for improper html format with mpdf strict rules

Tags: php, html, css, pdf, mpdf

i have facing the dynamic html format to `pdf` conversion it has multiple tables in a single `td` like

```
<table>
 <td>
  <table>1</table>
  <table>2</table>
  <table>3</table>
  <table>4</table>
  .....
 </td>
</table>`
```

In browser it is working fine but in `pdf` download it is not working with out the parent `td` the tables are printed in `pdf`. how to update the `mpdf` html conversion strict rules. Because in browser the format is supported.

Kindly help me with that

Answer (score 0):

PDF uses the same print functionality as the browser print. You can emulate that by using Chrome Developer Tools

[image: open more]

and emulate print rendering

[image: print emulate]

After that you could use the media print tag in css

```
@media print {
 …
}
```